# C# Rider - Aug 2022 - How to make that Debug and Hot-reload work properly?

Tags: c#, blazor, jetbrains-ide, rider, hot-reload

Is it my idea or Rider doesn't have implemented the Blazor / Hot Reload well?

I'm trying for more than 6 months Rider IDE from JetBrains, and I started to prefer against VS2022. But I recently started a new project with Blazor, and since then my opinion start to come down...

There is no way to debug a solution with multiple projects (as VS2022 does)... example, I have a single solution with 1 Server Project, 1 Client Project, and 1 Shared Project.

With VS2022 I was able to debug both projects without pain... but I tried for a month with Rider and is totally unpleasant... Am I the only one with this opinion?

There is a way to debug properly a solution with multiple projects in Rider and .Net 6 and using the Hot Reload feature?

Comment: That's not a question anyone other than JetBrains can answer properly, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RIDER

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should update your **launchSettings.json** like this. after that change your running profile to **httpsWatch**

This solution will work for Blazor

```json
    "httpsWatch": {
      "commandName": "Executable",
      "executablePath": "dotnet",
      "workingDirectory": "$(ProjectDir)",
      "hotReloadEnabled": true,
      "hotReloadProfile": "aspnetcore",
      "commandLineArgs": "watch run",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:3251;http://localhost:6362"
    },
```

Comment: This worked for me. I had to switch to the "https" profile and choose this running profile.

Comment: how does it work different than dotnet watch run comman in terminal? using this debugger doesnt work. it is the same thing as starting without debugger attached

Answer (score 2):

Press CTRL + ALT + 1 (above the Q button) and type:

```
dotnet watch run --project <projectName>
```

Comment: that is not a correct answer. this starts without debugger and you should stop it with Crtl+C every time. At least on the Mac.